# How do properly remove/clear a s3 bucket before re-using it in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am working in a jupyter notebook, creating and then saving a spark dataframe to s3 in python, using spark 2.0.1. The code looks something like

```
action = 'CREATE'
if action == 'CREATE':
    df = dfA.filter(...)
    df = df.join(...)
    df.coalesce(4).write.format('parquet').save('s3://my/path')
elif action == 'LOAD':
    df = spark.read.parquet('s3://my/path')
```

I think at some point, I had a bug and wrote a df which had 4 items in it (4 for a specific query) when it should only have 2 (every record was duplicated - probably because I was joining with something without first de-duping it).

After re-working things, I can verify that when I delete the old s3://my/path and then run that create logic so that it can write the location, my df has the 2 items I expect.

What I am confused about is that if I now run the LOAD logic, which should load the dataframe I just wrong with 2 items, replacing my df with the one read from s3, I get a dataframe with erroneous 4 items in it.

If I start over with a new path, `s3://my/path2`, then this exercise of creating and loading works.

It seems like a bug with s3, or maybe spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a bug,it could be the behaviour of s3, it has read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects ,eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES objects. when you delete a data and it might appear in list for some time, but eventually after some time when delete is fully propagated to all zones, it will list the correct data.(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel)

Answer (score -1):

I like @madhan-s answer, but my overwrites/re-read's were all done interactively, reloading pages on aws s3, checking that I couldn't read the object when it wasn't there, so I'm not sure this explains it (but thanks for that link! I need to learn that kind of stuff!)

Something that might have happened, is that I think I did

```
df = make_bad_df()
df.save_to_s3()
df = read_from_s3()
df.persist()
```

At that point, I would have persisted a dataframe I read from a particular s3 object - If I then delete and re-write that s3 bucket, and do something like

```
df2 = read_from_s3()
```

Spark has no way of knowing the s3 object has changed, maybe spark will say - aha! I've already persisted that dataframe, I'll just get it from memory/local disk?

Comment: -No, spark doesn't do that. you want to keep a dataset around, leave the variable alone. And yes, S3 consistency looks like it is making things worse.